# Bazel error "this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files" when building tensorflow for android

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build tensorflow for android. I'd like to use the `DecodeJpeg` op on android. Hence I've added the file, `decode_image_op.cc`, in which it is declared to build file.

This is the command I run to build tensorflow

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so  --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool  --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=arm64-v8a
```

This throws the following error

```
ERROR: /tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:4950:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_kernels':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_image_op.cc':
  '/tensorflow/core/lib/jpeg/jpeg_mem.h'
  '/tensorflow/core/platform/jpeg.h'
```

Where should I add these header files to resolve this error?

Comment: What exact modifications did you make, and to which BUILD file?

Comment: In `tensorflow\core\kernels\BUILD` file, I added `decode_image_op.cc` under `android_extended_ops_group1`. Once I started building it, bazel complained that `jerror.h`, `jpeglib.h`, `jconfig.h`, and `jmorecfg.h` were missing. I downloaded these headers from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/libjpeg) and placed them in `core/kernels` and `core/platform`. After this it proceeded smoothly, till this error showed up

Comment: @Jin Did the above comment answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can add the `cc_library` target `//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_image_op` in the `deps` attribute of the `cc_binary` target `//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so`.

`//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_image_op` already defines `decode_image_op.cc` and its dependencies.

Comment: I'm new to bazel. Did you mean this `cc_library(
    name = "decode_image",
    srcs = ["decode_image_op.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_image_op"
    ],`?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a need to create a new `cc_library` target. Try adding the target `//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_tensorflow_image_op`, which is defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L5115), to the dependencies of the target you're building, `//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so`.